# Pagination diplays always 2 pages

Tags: pagination, search, paged

I have a problem with the pagination its working great with blog page, but when i want to show custom post type it shows always two pages even if it contains just one post.

P.S. I modified in my function to display pages on select option but before that it was the same problem.

```
enter code here
if ( !function_exists( 'wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav' ) ) {
function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {

if( is_singular() )
    return;

global $wp_query;

/** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

/** Add current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 1 )
    $links[] = $paged;

/** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
}

if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
}

echo '<div class="navigation"><h3 class="filtttl">Pages</h3> ';?>
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get" class="filterform page">
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="voyage" />
<input type="hidden" id="s" name="s" value="" />
<select name="paged" id="pageselect" onchange="form.submit()">
<?php echo ' . "\n"';

/** Previous Post Link */
/*if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
    printf( '<option>%s</option>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );*/

/** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

    printf( '<option%s><a href="%s">%s</a></option>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
        echo '<option>…</option>';
}

/** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
sort( $links );
foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<option%s><a href="%s">%s</a></option>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
}

/** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
        echo '<option>…</option>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<option%s><a href="%s">%s</a></option>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
}

/** Next Post Link */
/*if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<option>%s</option>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );*/

echo '</select></form></div>' . "\n";

}
}
```

And in search page thats my code.

```
enter code here
<div class="intro">
        <div class="leftsearchform">
            <form method="get" role="search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="searchpage">
            <h2 class="srchttl">Rechercher votre voyage</h2>
                <input type="text" class="dest" name="dest" placeholder="Destination" />
                <input type="text" class="dep" name="dep" placeholder="Départ" />
                <input type="text" class="arr" name="arr" placeholder="Arrivée" />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="voyage" />
                <input type="hidden" id="s" name="s" value="" />
                <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Rechercher" />
            </form>
        </div><!-- !leftsearchform -->
        <div class="resultsearch">

            <div class="filtersrch">
                <?php $sort= $_GET['sort'];
                        if($sort == "Croissant")
                        {
                            $filter= "asc";
                        }
                        if($sort == "Decroissant")
                        {
                            $filter= "desc";
                        }
                        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                ?>
                <?php $temp = $voy_query; $voy_query= null;
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'voyages', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => $prx, 'order' => $filter, 'paged' => $paged, 's' =>$s, );
                $voy_query = new WP_Query($args);  ?>
                <h3 class="nbrrzlt"><?php echo $voy_query ->found_posts .' résultats.'; ?></h3>
                    <h3 class="filtttl">Prix</h3>
                    <form action="" method="get" class="filterform">
                    <!--<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="voyage" />-->
                    <input type="hidden" id="s" name="s" value="" />
                        <select name="sort" id="sorting" onchange="form.submit()">
                            <option value="Croissant" <?php if ($sort == "Croissant"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> >
                            Croissant</option>
                            <option value="Decroissant" <?php if ($sort == "Decroissant"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> 
                            selected="selected" >Decroissant</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                    <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
            </div><!-- !filtersrch -->
            <?php 
                if ($voy_query->have_posts()) : while ($voy_query->have_posts()) : $voy_query->the_post();
                    $post_id = get_the_ID();
```

EDIT:

```
// Load our function when hook is set
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );
function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $query ) {


// Check if on frontend and main query is modified
if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] = 'voyages' ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('meta_key', $prx);
    $query->set('meta_value', 'voyage[prx]');
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT2:**

```
function textdomain_include_search($query) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'voyages' ) );
    }
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'textdomain_include_search' );
```

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query. Your pagination is calculated from the main query. Your main query have more posts than the custom one, that is why you get two pages

Comment: @Pieter Goosen Thank you for this answer, can you see my edit if its correct because now the pagination doesn't show.

Comment: Where do you set the value of `$prx`?

Comment: @Milo $prx is a metabox but i added it just because i want to order by it. But for pagination i guess I missed something. the pre_get_filter is it correct and what i need to do in the query after that.

Comment: @pieter-goosen I added a new edit about the last function that i create but the pagination won't show so did i need to add something in search page.